# maven-javadoc-plugin Dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, javadoc

I'm trying to generate javadoc from maven-javadoc-plugin with simple configuration (see below)
Unfortunatly its seems to include all dependencies into javadoc classpath option:

-classpath
'D:/DEV/MyProject/target/classes;C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1/json-simple-1.1.1.jar; .....'

Then crash with "error in opening zip file"

even when i try to force includeDependencySources to false it does take them all :(

Any idea or good configuration to generate only package like org.mysite.* ?

Thanks

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <sourcepath>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourcepath>
        <includeDependencySources>false</includeDependencySources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do you know which file is causing the issue? Could it be that the file is not a zip/jar/war/ear, but for instance a pom?

Comment: This is a really simple project only including 10 classes (simple api client)
Here is the complete pom (feel free to make constructive remark on it :) ) http://pastebin.com/WMLGR4gw

and here is the complete output for a mvn javadoc:javadoc http://pastebin.com/jM533KKc

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Pom works on my machine. Does the real `C:\Users\me\` contain special characters?

Comment: I deleted my complete .m2/repo directory .... just run with same config... and it passed -_-
Thanks any way for your help